# How do I create a textfield or label inside a cell programmatically?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a tableview with 5 cells.  I have added a UIImageView with storyboard and set those uiimageview.image properties to an image.  However, the image is placed a few pixels to the right of the edge of the cell (following HIG) I suppose.  How do I set the image so that it starts at the beginning left edge of the cell?

[image]

Comment: Are you using `UITableViewCell`'s `UIImageView` or it's added by you?

Comment: Originally i just dropped the image in from the media library.  But then i dragged in a uiimageview and set the uiimageview.image property programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Say you are setting your label like so:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, <width>, <height>)];
```

Try this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initFrame:CGRectMake(-10, 0, <width>, <height>)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in the interface builder, check the cell and image view's x, y property.

or programmatically,

```
CGFloat width = cell.frame.size.width, height = 40;
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
UITextField * tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
[cell addSubView:label] 
or 
[cell addSubView:tf];
```